# DatagridView con columnas autofiltrantes, problema con paquete Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, nuget

soy nuevo programando en c# y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

para poder crear un **datagridview** con columnas **autofiltrantes** (estilo excel), instalé un paquete **Nuget**, **DataGridViewAutoFilter** (por zqb) versión 1.0.0

El problema es que aunque la instalación ha ido bien (de hecho aparece en la sección de Referencias del explorador de soluciones), **no aparece en el Cuadro de Herramientas** ningún objeto "DataGridViewAutoFilter"...

¿Es posible que me falte algún paso?

Por si sirve de algo, estas son las actualizaciones de Framework:
KB2468871, KB2468871V2, KB2478063, KB2533523, KB2544514, KB2600211, KB2600217, KB2468871, KB2468871V2, KB2478063, KB2533523, KB2544514, KB2600211, KB2600217

Muchas gracias,
Fernando

Comment: Seguiste la documentacion?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!